# Посему не работает left outer join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Что происходит, почему выводит все соответствия? не понимаю, в таблице credit_product есть продукт с кодом qwe и в таблице marketing_campaign_product_code  есть запись с кодом qwe. Мне надо все записи в таблице credit_product для которых нет соответсвий в таблице marketing_campaign_product_code

`select p.* from credit_product p left outer join marketing_campaign_product_code c on p.code = c.credit_product_code;`

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: так а где в запросе хоть что, отвечающее на вопрос "для которых нет соответсвий"?

Comment: @Мелкий затупил, where c.credit_product_code is null

Comment: Если условие именно такое как вы указали в комментарии всё должно быть правильно.